# how to create a rectangle through the lat and lon and finding area of the rectangle?

Tags: math, geometry, rectangles, bounding-box

I have a data of latitude and longitude and calculated distance points, I plotted those points and I can see that those points are not moving anywhere, except just covered very small distance in a lot of time, I want to check how much area is covered by these kind of points?  or how can I create the rectangle surrounding this and calculate the area of the that rectangle? or bounding box? or any other suggestions??

how can I do that any mathematical formulas to do that? any suggestions?

Comment: The simplest way - get minimum and maximum values of coordinates and make bounding box.

Comment: @MBo can you recommend me any reference code for bounding box in python, I have calculated the min and max values for lat and lon

Comment: That's all - these values define a box in lat/lon cordinates (curved trapezoid on Earth surface)